# Is there anything like "ilike many" in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I am trying to solve the following problem. I want to check if a string is even with multiple options of strings case insensitive in Clickhouse.

```
select first_name ilike ('', ' ', 'None') as first_name from people;
```

I couldn't find a satisfying solution until now. Can somebody give me a hint? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-search-functions#multisearchany

multiSearchAnyCaseInsensitive
multiSearchAnyCaseInsensitiveUTF8

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-search-functions#multifuzzymatchany

https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/ff7d7a06-b87d-49f3-bb3a-43cbdf455a54

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (name String) ENGINE=Memory as
select * from values(('John'), ('Ksenia'), ('Alice'));
  
SELECT * FROM users 
  where multiSearchAnyCaseInsensitiveUTF8(name, ['john', 'ali'])
format PrettyCompact;

+-name--+
| John  |
| Alice |
+-------+
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much.